# Bad performance in Dota2, AMD drivers fault or Wine fault?

Tags: ati, wine, games, steam, winetricks

Tried to play Dota 2 through Wine and got terrible performance, is it AMD drivers fault or generally Wine fault?
If it's AMD drives fault, does NVIDIA have better drivers for linux based systems?

My hardware:
1. i7 3770k.
2. AMD HD6870.
3. 8GB of RAM.

Did the above steps on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit with default window manager.

1. Installed AMD drivers through software sources.
2. Installed Wine1.5:
   a. Changed wine to work in 32bit mode.
   b. Added d3dx9, dotnet, dwrite, wininet and vcrun20005/8 through winetricks.
3. Installed steam through Wine.
4. Installed Dota 2.
5. Tried to play Dota 2, fps was around 60-70 but the animation was jumpy and 
   generally performance was bad.
6. Just for testing i removed fglrx drivers, and stayed with the standard ones, fps
   in Dota 2 was low around 8-15fps, but animation wasn't glitchy or jumpy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wineHQ, Dota 2 was tested successfully on Wine 1.5.24. Tested Ubuntu systems are 12.10 and 13.04 alpha.

It did not work in their test environment. Here is the report.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24458&iTestingId=77046

Here is an abstract taken from there

**Selected Test Results (selected in 'Test Results' table below)**
What works
Loading the game, starting game, changing settings, creating parties.

**What does not**
Playing the game more than 15 minutes results in unrecoverable crash. Restarting the game does not allow continue due to long stuttering.

**What was not tested**
Finishing a game.

**Additional Comments**
Reproducible crashes after 15 minutes. *Don't* play public matchmaking, you won't be able to return to the game if it lasts longer than 15 minutes.

Hence, DOTA 2 is still not fully supported by Wine. :(  Try native games like http://www.heroesofnewerth.com/  which has a Linux version.

Comment: Alright, that's sad to hear. I'll wait for Dota 2 to work natively on linux. Do you know if NVIDIA Drivers work better under linux?